# onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: No such file: /etc/onvif/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl

Tags: python, ip-camera, python-onvif

I have bought a V380 ip camera  avaiable at https://www.daraz.pk/products/i1977066-s1481128974.html?urlFlag=true&mp=1 . I am trying to implement onvif client in Python.
When I run the following code

```
from onvif import ONVIFCamera

mycam = ONVIFCamera('192.168.10.12', 8899, 'admin', '', '/etc/onvif/wsdl/')
resp = mycam.devicemgmt.GetHostname()
print( 'My camera`s hostname: ' + str(resp.Name))
```

I get following error

```
onvif.exceptions.ONVIFError: Unknown error: No such file: /etc/onvif/wsdl/devicemgmt.wsdl
```

Answer (score 4):

Modify the following path `/etc/onvif/wsdl/`
to where you have the wsdl file. By default, you have it in `/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` .

if you are using environments, check `/your env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wsdl`